# how to call a controller with express routes and include a defined parameter

Tags: node.js, express, routes

//in routes.js (a rough attempt of what I want)

```
app.get('/test', myCtrl.test(req, res, next, 'type1'));
```

//in myCtrl.js

```
exports.test = function(req, res, next, type){
    res.jsonp(type);
};
```

Like this it gives an error: ReferenceError: req is not defined

Answer (score 2):

Wrap that in an anonymous function else it will exec right away:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    myCtrl.test(req, res, next, 'type1');
})
```

Comment: if I call another function in the 'next' it says that req is undefined