# req undefined when called from next()

Tags: node.js, express, routes, undefined

//in routes.js

```
test  = require('test');

app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  test.first(
    req,res,
    test.second,
    'info'
  );
});
```

//in test.js

```
exports.first= function(req, res, next, inf){
    req.test= inf;
    console.log(inf); //info
    next();
};
exports.second= function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req); //undefined
    res.jsonp(req.test);//error :s
};
```

This is a follow up question from [how to call a controller with express routes and include a defined parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26220473/how-to-call-a-controller-with-express-routes-and-include-a-defined-parameter)

Comment: where did u call second?

Comment: in the next() of test.first

Comment: where exactly is that in above code?

Comment: the first block in routes and the second in test.js which is called like: test= require('test.js');

Comment: in above code you put, second function is not even been invoked. there is no `next()` happenig first

Comment: line 4 of first block ;)

Comment: in line 4 you passed to second as parameter next. where did u invoke it?

Comment: edited, it is invoked, the comments in front of log is what the console prints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are calling `next();` in `test.first()`, that means you passing no arguments to `test.second()`. So with your current setup you need to do `next(req, res);` in `test.first()` instead.